# Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > invalid source release: 1.7

Tags: java, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am using :

1. gradle-2.3
2. javac -version = 1.7
3. jre = 1.7
4. regedit shows it is pointing to 1.7.

But I am still getting below error

> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > invalid source release: 1.7

Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 22):

You can set the JDK Version used by gradle for the build by adding a "gradle.properties" file to your project. Add the following property:

```
org.gradle.java.home = <Path to the JDK you want to use for your project>
```

I agree with the previous answer that you also should check if the JDK and the sourceCompatibility match.

Comment: <3, it was driving me crazy - btw fot those with same problem I messed up my project by installing older version of java to support Adobe Illustrator on Mac and this helped

Comment: Pointed me to root cause: I forgot to set Gradle JVM in `Ctrl+Alt+S/Build Tools/Gradle/Gradle JVM` after upgrading JDK.

Answer (score 14):

You say you are running with Java 7, but are you really sure?

Because as far as I know that error occurs precisely when you are using a source / target level that is not supported by the JVM you are running gradle with. So if I were to take a guess I'd say that gradle seems to think your JDK doesn't support Java 7 (so its JDK 6 or lower)

Maybe double check that

a) Gradle itself is running with JDK 7. If you run gradle from within Eclipse using the STS gradle tooling, it will use the workspace default JRE to run gradle. Check that it is at least a JDK 7. (Go to "Windows >> Preferences >> Java >> Installed JRE". The JRE with a 'check mark' is the one Gradle will run with).

b) Gradle may accidentally pick up another JDK to compile stuff with if it finds an environment variable 'JAVA_HOME'. So double check that it isn't pointing to a JDK 6 or lower.

Comment: In my case, the PATH was correct, but the JAVA_HOME was wrong

Comment: In my case my IntelliJ project had java 1.8, but Gradle JVM was 1.7. Changed Gradle JVM in Preferences and everything works now

Answer (score 5):

- To check if the `$JAVA_HOME` is really to point the default java

  ```
  echo $JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk
  ```
- Check Java version

  ```
  java -version
  openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
  ```
- If misaligned like above, to modify `$JAVA_HOME` in the `/etc/profile` (or alternatively the .profile/.bashprofile/ in your user's home directory), let point to

  ```
  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
  ```
- BTW: solved at `Centos7` to fix Invalid release 1.8

Answer (score 4):

If you have tried all solutions viz -

1. Fixing your JAVA_HOME and Java run time
2. Fixing you Gradle JVM version in preferences
3. Setting up the org.gradle.java.home =

still you face the issue then check your build.gradle file and look if `sourceCompatibility = '17'`  is present alone. If yes comment it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in your build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

If this does not work please provide the contents of your build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Gradle ran on JRE instead of **JDK** (wrong set of JAVA_HOME).
Pointing my JAVA_HOME to the root of the JDK fixed the build.
(Of course, assuming your PATH has %JAVA_HOME%\bin)

*Reason*:

The JDK has the javac for compiling java while the JRE does not.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the "bug" with 1.8 java

Solved: Findbugs showed me an ü in a method title ( not allowed in graddle)

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to change the value of `sourceCompatibility` property in `build.gradle` file to be something less than or equal current version [I've v. 16, and changed the `sourceCompatibility` to v. 11]

[image]

Comment: There's like 20 of these in Ghidra that I got this error on.  Which build.gradle was it in your case?

Answer (score 0):

It's suggesting that the code is being compiled with a JDK version that doesn't support the specified source level.
In mine case I am having jdk version 11 configured on my system but initially in gradle it was 17. So, I need to change it to version 11 in mine build.gradle. (Note:- change both sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility with the version of jdk you are having in ur system)

```
java {
sourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11) // 17 ->11
targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11)  // 17-> 11
}
```