# Getting SpringBoot error - Execution failed for task ':compileJava

Tags: spring-boot

The below is my build.gradle.

When I Bootrun, i get the error
**Execution failed for task ':compileJava**
**invalid source release: 18**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.9'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.loginapp'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '18'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450923/execution-failed-for-task-compilejava-invalid-source-release-1-7

Comment: Do you have JDK 18 installed? Is Gradle using that JDK?

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes .. I installed. I also checked java -version in my Command prompt. it is 18 only

Comment: @sabari Did you also configured JDK 18 to be your Java home?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using IntelliJ, shared the screenshot and told us you alread checked the java version and I already got this error a few times here is my *TODO* I go through when I get this error:

1. Do what you showed us on the screenshot (Check Project Version and language level)
2. Do the same for Modules (Project Structure > Modules) **Don't forget the Dependencies Tab** there you can find the module SDK
3. Check Java Compiler (Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler) there you can see a `Project bytecode version` & `Per-module bytecode version` -> Check those

Hope this works :)